# Covariance gets lost when deriving from covariant interface

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, covariance

In our C# .NET WinForm application we have a custom control named `ControlWithLabel`. I want to enhance it via templates to `ControlWithLabel<TControl>`. The problem is, we have hundreds of checks like `if (something is ControlWithLabel)` and the tested object can be of multiple derived types (TextBoxWithLabel, ComboBoxWithLabel, etc.). How can I transform it to a template solution without the need to rewrite every check and multiply it with every possibility, like `if (something is ControlWithLabel<TextBox>) || (something is ControlWithLabel<ComboBox>) || ... etc ...` ?

I tried to use a covariant interface, but it's not working as I'm expecting. Covariance of the interface gets lost when deriving to a general non-template interface.

```
public class ControlWithLabel<TControl> : IControlWithLabel<TControl> where TControl : Control, new()
{
    public ControlWithLabel()
    {
        this.Control = new TControl();
        this.Label = new Label();
    }

    public Label Label
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public TControl Control
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class ControlWithLabel : ControlWithLabel<Control>, IControlWithLabel
{
}

public interface IControlWithLabel<out TControl> where TControl : Control
{
    Label Label
    {
        get;
    }

    TControl Control
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface IControlWithLabel : IControlWithLabel<Control>
{
}

public class TextBoxWithLabel : ControlWithLabel<TextBox>
{
    public void SpecialMethodForTextBox()
    {
        // Special code ...
    }
}

public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void _buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxWithLabel textBoxWithLabel = new TextBoxWithLabel();

        // this works, but then I need to rewrite and multiply every check
        if (textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<TextBox>)
            MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<TextBox>");

        // this is not working, since classes cannot be covariant
        if (textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<Control>)
            MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<Control>");

        // this is not working at all
        if (textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel)
            MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel");

        // this works, but then I need to rewrite and multiply every check
        if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<TextBox>)
            MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<TextBox>");

        // this works, but then I need to rewrite every check
        if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<Control>)
            MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<Control>");

        // this is not working - covariance is lost!! Why?
        if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel)
            MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel");
    }
}
```

What should I do to be able to generally use `if (something is ControlWithLabel)` or `if (something is IControlWithLabel)` instead of `if (something is IControlWithLabel<Control>)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all other answers I finally found a solution. None of the answers made it possible to use the general `ControlWithLabel.Control` and `IControlWithLabel.Control`. So here is my solution:

```
public interface IControlWithLabel
{
    Label Label
    {
        get;
    }

    Control Control
    {
        get;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Here we use covariance
/// </summary>
public interface IControlWithLabel<out TControl> : IControlWithLabel where TControl : Control, new()
{
    new TControl Control
    {
        get;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Common base, never instantiated
/// </summary>
public abstract class ControlWithLabel : IControlWithLabel
{
    protected Control _control;

    public ControlWithLabel()
    {
        this.Label = new Label();
    }

    public Label Label
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This property cannot be marked as 'abstract', because we want to change the return type in descendants
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Control Control
    {
        get
        {
            return _control;
        }
    }
}

public class ControlWithLabel<TControl> : ControlWithLabel, IControlWithLabel<TControl> where TControl : Control, new()
{
    public ControlWithLabel() : base()
    {
        this.Control = new TControl();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// We cannot use 'override', since we want to return TControl instead of Control
    /// </summary>
    public new TControl Control
    {
        get
        {
            return _control as TControl;

            // This will return null if _control is not TControl.
            // This can happen, when we make an explicit cast for example TextBoxWithLabel to ComboBoxWithLabel, which requires an explicit conversion operator implementation.
            // In such case there can be still used general ControlWithLabel.Control, which always will be "not null" - for example ((ControlWithLabel)someObject).Control
            // (the general ControlWithLabel.Control will always be "not null", because the base class ControlWithLabel is marked as abstract and current class ControlWithLabel<TControl> creates the control in the constructor).
        }

        private set
        {
            _control = value;
        }
    }
}

public class TextBoxWithLabel : ControlWithLabel<TextBox>
{
    public void SpecialMethodForTextBox()
    {
        // Special code ...
    }
}

public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void _buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxWithLabel textBoxWithLabel = new TextBoxWithLabel();

        // This works
        if (textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<TextBox>)
        {
            // We can use the general ControlWithLabel.Control
            if (((ControlWithLabel)textBoxWithLabel).Control != null)
                MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<TextBox>");
        }

        // This is not working, since classes cannot be covariant
        if (textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<Control>)
        {
            // We can use the general ControlWithLabel.Control
            if (((ControlWithLabel)textBoxWithLabel).Control != null)
                MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel<Control>");
        }

        // This works!
        if (textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel)
        {
            // We can use the general ControlWithLabel.Control
            if (((ControlWithLabel)textBoxWithLabel).Control != null)
                MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is ControlWithLabel");
        }

        // This works
        if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<TextBox>)
        {
            // We can use the general INTERFACE property IControlWithLabel.Control
            if (((IControlWithLabel)textBoxWithLabel).Control != null)
                MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<TextBox>");
        }

        // This works thanks to COVARIANCE
        if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<Control>)
        {
            // We can use the general INTERFACE property IControlWithLabel.Control
            if (((IControlWithLabel)textBoxWithLabel).Control != null)
                MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<Control>");
        }

        // This works!
        if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel)
        {
            // We can use the general INTERFACE property IControlWithLabel.Control
            if (((IControlWithLabel)textBoxWithLabel).Control != null)
                MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel");
        }
    }
}
```

Covariance is not really needed in this case, but it's good to have the possibility to check `if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel<Control>)`. It can be useful in some cases.

This solution is tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing some requirement, you don't need covariance?

```
public interface IControlWithLabel
{
    Label Label { get; }
}

public interface IControlWithLabel<TControl> : IControlWithLabel where TControl : Control, new()
{  
    TControl Control { get;}
}

//never instantiated, common base
public abstract class ControlWithLabel : IControlWithLabel
{
}

public class ControlWithLabel<TControl> : ControlWithLabel, IControlWithLabel<TControl>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interface inheritance is backwards. Create `interface IControlWithLabel`, then have `IControlWithLabel<T>` inherit from `IControlWithLabel`. Then all instances of `IControlWithLabel<T>` are also `IControlWithLabel`.

Comment: Jesus! You're right! Thank you. I'll write the correct code in a separate answer.

Comment: Hmm ... but ... how can I use the properties of the interface, when I switch the order of inheritance and in the code all I know is the fact, that the object is some ControlWithLabel and has a Control and a Label?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation needs to inherit both the generic and the non-generic interfaces as such:

```
public class TextBoxWithLabel : ControlWithLabel<TextBox>
{
    public void SpecialMethodForTextBox()
    {
        // Special code ...
    }
}

public class ControlWithLabel<TControl> 
    IControlWithLabel, 
    IControlWithLabel<TControl> where TControl : Control, new()
{
    public ControlWithLabel()
    {
        Control = new TControl();
        Label = new Label();
    }

    public Label Label { get; private set; }

    public TControl Control { get; private set; }
}

public interface IControlWithLabel<out TControl> where TControl : Control
{
    Label Label { get; }

    TControl Control { get; }
}

public interface IControlWithLabel
{
    Label Label { get; }
}
```

Then you should be able to do the following:

```
var textBoxWithLabel = new TextBoxWithLabel();

// This will work just fine
if (textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel)
{
    MessageBox.Show("textBoxWithLabel is IControlWithLabel");
}
```

The only issue is then that you will lose the `.Control` property, unless you do check for `is IControlWithLabel<TextBox>`.